# Automatically displaying images on package links

Tags: feature-request

The current package image system on links is very manual. Too manual. You have to remember or look up a URL, insert an image, blah blah blah. Not to forget we're currently having to go through a messy database search-replace to change the images. Nasty.

Could we instead just add some javascript to the page that detected the package links and added a CSS class to them. Something as simple as this would work:

```
$('a[href^="http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/"]').addClass('packageLink');
```

And then some CSS to display the image:

```
a.packageLink {
    background:url(...) center right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 20px
}
h1 a.packageLink, h2 a.packageLink, h3 a.packageLink {
    /* bigger version for headers */
    background-image:url(...);
    padding-right: 25px
}
```

I'm guessing on all those padding values, but the idea is solid.

Then somebody only needs link to the package url, and an image pops up.

Comment: Sounds clever... but what about all of the existing links that already have the image?

Comment: May I post a more general feature request on MSO that supersedes this?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Somebody could write up a quick script for [The Bot](http://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) to run, that would edit those images out. It wouldn't take too long, I think.